# When does fetch happen from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have an application that triggers the  job to the spark master. But when I check the IP address executing the job, its displaying my application IP and not the spark worker IP. So, from what I understand, the call on RDD generates a spark worker to work.

But my question is this.

```
CassandraSQLContext c = new CassandraSQLContext(sc);

QueryExecution q=c.executeSql(cqlCommand); //-----1

q.toRDD().count(); //----2
```

I saw the worker doing something for 2 but nothing for 1.

So does this mean fetch from Cassandra and RDD creation out of it in 1 is all done in the application?

If so, 2 does trigger a job to two workers. In that case, does it fetch again from Cassandra and process the count?

Can someone clarify this??

**EDIT**

1. Going by the answer provided, if the count call triggers the workers to function, then what is the use of executeSQL creating a RDD in local? Does that create a Cassandra dataset of the data by querying ? If that's the case, querying from Cassandra happens twice?

2.. If spark automatically distributes the computations of 10 partitions of Cassandra among 4 workers, who will aggregate the results? Master is just doing the distribution. So does it aggregate too?

3. If I don't cache the RDD and do another count operation, what will happen? Will spark try to to use the same worker that was used previously for a particular partition and append to the result RDD in that node. I think it has to query Cassandra to get this partition data again? Can you provide some clarity in this?
4. If I cache my RDD, what happens? RDD is stored in the worker and it will be used for all operations? In that case, how this is different from we storing a dataset in memory and processing it? Let me know if an right about this too.

Answer (score 3):

Spark loading and transformations of RDD's like your CQL command are lazily evaluated.

Actions trigger all of the precursor transformations to be run, so in your example, count() is an action.

The way Spark works internally is that it builds up a graph of transformations.  When it needs to run an action, it will break the graph up into separate sub-tasks that can be run by the individual workers.

To do a single action like count(), the data will only be fetched from Cassandra once, and if possible, the RDD for each executor would be populated from the data that is local to each Cassandra node.

If you do another action on the RDD created from q, it may still be cached in memory and will be reused.  There are API calls you can make to explicitly request that an RDD be cached in memory if you plan to re-use it.

Comment: That answers the point 2 but what about point 1. executeSql method triggers a fetch from Cassandra on the application side. Can you provide some clarity on that?

Comment: And one more thing. If spark automatically distributes the computations of 10 partitions of Cassandra among 4 workers, who will aggregate the results? Master is just doing the distribution. So does it aggregate too?

Comment: Add this one too. When I don't.cache the RDD and do another count operation on the same RDD, what will happen?

Comment: You should start new questions rather than add questions on to this one.  Where results are aggregated depends on the action.  If the action was save to Cassandra, each executor would save its slice of a transformed RDD to Cassandra in parallel.  If the action is count, each executor generates a count for its slice, and then the spark driver would aggregate those sub-task counts.